# Accessing the token in the GET route handler NextJS 13.4

Tags: next.js, axios, fetch-api, next-auth

I'm currently using nextauth with the most up to date version of nextjs and currently can't get the token in the route handlers unless they're hit from the client.

I've tried the examples I've found online.

```
// /api/test/route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function GET(req) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });

  console.log(token);

  return NextResponse.json({
    message: "Success!",
    token,
  });
}

// /test/page.js
const Test = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test");

  const data = await res.json();

  console.log("CLIENT- ", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This doesn't work, it returns null for the token both. If I however go to the url bar and hit the api directly at http://localhost:3000/api/test then both console.logs return a full token with all the expected data. Also if I call the API from a client page it works like so:

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";

const Test = () => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/test");

    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I get this to work on a server page?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request from the browser it passes on things it knows from previous requests to the same domain, like cookies and credentials. Your page, however, is a server component that does not use the browser when making the fetch request and does not pass along things like cookies and credentials.

To get the current credentials from your server component (`test/page.js`), you need to use Next's helpers to read [`cookies()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) or [`headers()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers).

You can then do things like:

```js
// test/page.js

const Test = async () => {
    const headersList = headers();
    const token = headersList.get("Authorization");
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });

   //...
}
```

Note that I didn't check where Next-Auth puts the credentials (cookie or auth header) so you will need to adapt your code to that to make this work.

Good luck!